# Debugging Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, operating-system, performance-testing

I'm trying to figure out where my memory leak is coming from since lately i'm experiencing a lot of performance drop when just opening a new tab on my browser FireFox ver.51
Just to be sure I've disabled all non-Microsoft startup services in msconfig even after reboot it still gets stuck on this.
Looking up on the vendors updates for this machine then it would be up to date on the drivers, i do occasionally check for Intel Chipset and onboard Graphics drivers (stable versions only) myself that are a few years newer then the vendor.

[MS Resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWLz8.png)

[MS Taskmgr Perfomance monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDVxo.png)

In the Taskmgr Performance monitor you can see I'm barely using any CPU and I/O leaving out any form of I/O wait issues due to swapping.

When looking in the Resource monitor actual physical RAM in is about 6.3GB while Cached is only 1.6GB making it roughly 4GB RAM missing where it's usage is coming from.

So i did do a offline MemTest (oh yes the old blue gorgeous BIOS screen) and all checks were passed, luckily it's only 8GB RAM so the downtime is manage-able ;)

Any ideas or other handy tools I can use to find the culprit?

Comment: Doesn't really look like a leak because it's stable over time. Do you have an ad blocker like uBlock Origin running? I found installing it really helps FireFox. Note in JavaScript that it can never be known that an object will be needed again, so allocations can accumulate, but in your case it doesn't appear to be exceeding the initial allocation space.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it, seems like my pagefile is storing too much cached memory for some reason, will look into it myself why it stores so much memory